# why am I getting a 404 not found error when I try to submit a form on my localhost website

Tags: php

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.10 Server at localhost Port 8080

when i input data into a form on my website i receive this error instead of being redirected to the signin page with php function header()

```
<main>
    <div>
        <section>
            <h1>Signup</h1>
            <form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="password" name="pwd-repeat" placeholder="Repeat Password">
            <button type="submit" name="signup-submit">Signup</button>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>




if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {

    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

   if (empty($username) || empty($username) || empty($username) || empty($username)) {
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
   } 


}
```

the top code is the signup.php page and the bottom code is the include file signup.inc.php not sure why im being directed to the loguout.inc.php file when i try to submit this form

Logout

i just found that this code in my header page ^ was what was making the above form navigate to logout.inc.php when i click signup but there is no correlation between the two. Does anyone know why the signup form is doing that, thank you

Comment: im using xampp and the index page is running fine until i submit my form i get the above error ^ any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: What is the requested URL? You can find it in the address bar of your browser.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/login%20system/includes/logout.inc.php

Comment: This contradicts your response to Gabriel's question. This says 'logout' and that said 'signup'.

Comment: yeah i dont know why its directing to the logout.inc.php file this is just an include file that isnt directly part of the site

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?